# jQuery addClass based on how far scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have written some jquery to calculate the height of 4 elements by css class and get their height, then compare the height to how far the page has been scrolled.  If the page has been scrolled to or past each element then a css class is added which animates the element.

The problem that I am having is that the jquery is adding the classes to all of the elements as soon as the page is scrolled to the first element, instead of adding the class to each as it is scrolled to.

What is wrong with my jquery that it is doing this?

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/94kP6/7/

This is the jquery part of the code

```
// element animation scroll detection
(function ($, document, undefined) {
    var animation1 = $('.animation1').height();
    var animation2 = $('.animation2').height();
    var animation3 = $('.animation3').height();
    var animation4 = $('.animation4').height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(winTop >= (animation1)){
        $('.animation1').addClass("animate-from-left");
        }
        if(winTop >= (animation2)){
        $('.animation2').addClass("animate-from-right");
        }
        if(winTop >= (animation3)){
        $('.animation3').addClass("animate-from-left");
        }
        if(winTop >= (animation4)){
        $('.animation4').addClass("animate-from-right");
        }
    });
})(jQuery, document);
```

Comment: You probably want to check for the element height + the element offset (or position).

Comment: Each element's height is 100-200 pixels, so you scroll past that pretty early. You need to find each element's distance from the the top of the page.

Comment: You are using "height" instead of scrollTop or offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var animation1 = $('.animation1').height();
var animation2 = $('.animation2').height();
var animation3 = $('.animation3').height();
var animation4 = $('.animation4').height();
```

needs to be

```
var animation1 = $('.animation1').offset().top;
var animation2 = $('.animation2').offset().top;
var animation3 = $('.animation3').offset().top;
var animation4 = $('.animation4').offset().top;
```

or some variant for personal preference, like this:

```
var animation1 = $('.animation1').position().top - $('.animation1').height();
var animation2 = $('.animation2').position().top - $('.animation2').height();
var animation3 = $('.animation3').position().top - $('.animation3').height();
var animation4 = $('.animation4').position().top - $('.animation4').height();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle to show you need to use `.offset().top` instead of `.height`

http://jsfiddle.net/94kP6/10/

When you use `height`, you are asking the scroll to wait until **the height of the object** instead of waiting for the **top position of the object**

Just change your `height`s to `offset`s

**UPDATE**
http://jsfiddle.net/94kP6/14/
This makes it so the animation can be seen more in the middle of the screen.  Just subtract a specified height (in this case, the height of the object) from the offset and it will animate at a higher scrollTop.

You can also do the same thing, only backwards by ADDING a specified amount to the `var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();` line, line this: `var winTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 250;`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but one thing, in your jsfiddle the element doesn't get the animation until it is at the very top of the window.  Is there a way to do it right when it comes into view at the bottom, or even better, 250px up from the bottom?

Comment: I just changed the if statement to "if(winTop >= (animation1-350)){" and that seems to work.

Comment: @fender967 Perfect!  I've updated the fiddles and added an explanation.